# Roughly how long to single-handedly install a metal roof?

Tags: roof, roofing, metal-roof

I am preparing to replace my roof in the new year, either hire someone to do shingles, or, I really like the idea of doing a standing seam snaplock metal roof myself.  However, my weakness is time estimation.

How long would it take to install a metal roof, alone (assume I could get the panels craned to the roof on delivery)?  I would most likely strip the shingles first.  I am confident on the roof, fairly skilled for a layman, and in reasonable shape.  I intend to learn how to do it from youtube videos and reading the pro's argue about the best way to do things!

The house roof is something like 50'x 40 with a dormer style extension.

[image: Roof front]

[image: Roof back]

Comment: I am confident on a shingle roof also, but new metal roof worries me, they can be slippery.   Some people just nail furrings on top of shingles and screw the metal onto to them.  Should take a few full days to do it(5 to7 days), those vents will tend to be slow.

Comment: I think this is a situation that calls for the 2(n+1) estimation rule. Think it'll take a day? Estimate 2 weeks. Think it'll take a week? Estimate two months.

Comment: Wow! look at all those penetrations you will have to deal with, 12! from what we can see in the 2 pics. And as Ecnerwal mentions, handling long unwieldy sheets of metal will be hard for 1 person. This is definitely a situation where 2 people will be more than twice as fast as 1.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with "one person metal roofing" in the normal long unwieldy strips of metal manner is precisely that it's vary hard for one person to effectively manipulate the sheets on the roof. If the roof is "50x40" you're looking at 20+ foot long sheets to go ridge to eave, and those can be difficult even if you get perfect weather, which is not typically the case over the length of such a project. Add wind and/or rain and it can get ugly.

Shingles are far more manageable for one person working alone, because the unit size is such that you can work effectively. There are "shingle-sized" metal systems on the market now, I have not looked at them extensively, but they might offer a useful alternative to trying to do standing seam by yourself without a helper.

Both those numerous vents (as mentioned in a comment) and the valley(s) are places that will slow you down. For standing seam, the vents will slow you way down.